# Buddhism's views on environmental stewardship questions

Tags: ethics

1)  What does Buddhism’s religious texts say about the environment

2)  How much importance is placed environmental stewardship in Buddhism

3)  What is Buddhism’s beliefs on humans living with the environment

4)  What do Buddhism’s religious figures state about environmental stewardship

5)  Are the teachings of Buddhism related to environmental stewardship open for interpretation

Comment: Hi John and Welcome to Buddhism.SE! You've submitted some interesting questions but it might be best if they are split up and submitted as several different questions. Our Welcome page has useful information for getting started on the site. 
http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post

Comment: See also [Are ecological concerns supported explicitly in Buddhism?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2754/254)

Comment: Hello John and welcome to Buddhism SE. Nice to see such interest and enthusiasm for learning. As Robin said it might be a good idea to split up your questions. This way it will be easier for other people to answer and you will probably get better and more precise answers.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold... Please flag it for reopening if it can be pared down to a single question. Also, feel free to post new questions for each issue.

Comment: This free downloadable book might have something useful for you. http://www.buddhistelibrary.org/en/displayimage.php?album=15&pid=1606#top_display_media

Comment: ["The Buddhist Attitude Towards Nature"](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/desilva/attitude.html)