# Does the Buddha specifically said about saving environment?

Tags: ethics, teaching, buddha

Does the Buddha specifically mentioned anything about saving environment or planet in His teachings?

If yes, what He said?

If no, then Buddhist organizations need not to concern about environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are ecological concerns supported explicitly in Buddhism?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2754/157)